# Would it be possible to create a perpetual motion machine in an environment without air, friction, or dissipation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, drag, dissipation, perpetual-motion

[Perpetual motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion) machines don't work because as it moves, the air molecules hit it and slow it down. Friction slows it down in a similar way. If there were no forces to slow it down, could it work?

Comment: If you start throwing out the laws of physics anything is possible.

Comment: Why do you think gravity slows things down? In Newtonian gravity, two gravitationally bound masses can be in orbit forever. The Earth has been orbiting the Sun for a long time.

Comment: Orbiting objects radiate gravitational waves.  I guess that's not Newtonian though

Comment: The implication behind creating a perpetual motion machine is that you can get "free energy" out of it.  You can't.  Even if you create such a device, you can't get more energy out of it than you originally put into it, meaning that the attempt to create such a device is a total waste of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be an example of what wikipedia calls a perpetual motion machine of the third kind, a machine that does not produce excess energy, but is able to move for a long time due to reduction of losses.  Losses do not have to be air resistance, so removing (as much as possible) air does not remove all loss.

Wikipedia has a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion#Low_friction) of some examples of low-loss systems.  No system is perfect and losses eventually accumulate, although it may require astronomical timescales before the losses become significant.  Basically the idea of "removing all forces" is an ideal, not practically reachable.  Even as such systems approach the ideal, they still contain a finite amount of extractable energy.  Any attempt to remove more energy than that finite amount will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if there are no energy dissipative forces perpetual motion would be possible. The thing is, there are always dissipative forces. Even the vacuum of outer space is not completely empty. To quote Wikipedia, "it contains a low density of particles, predominantly a plasma of hydrogen and helium, as well as electromagnetic radiation, magnetic fields, neutrinos, dust, and cosmic rays". Collision with the particles will eventually dissipate the energy of a moving object, albeit very very slowly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

No, unless you throw quantum mechanics out of the way too.
This is because, even if there was no air drag or friction or whatever due to some reason, due to operators in the hamiltonian kf any system having a communication relation between them, one can see that even on very weak coupling to the environment, you have dissipation.
Now, you might say that you can remove the coupling altogether, but thats not possible since it means that the machine doesn't interact with electromagnetic waves or gravitational waves(has no mass basically) or any other field as such. That would simply mean the machine is not made lf any know matter and you can't really "see" it.

Comment: A superconducting loop carrying a current would come awfully close to being non-dissipative.  Similarly a perfectly spherical mass spinning in a perfect vacuum would spin pretty much forever.  There might be argument about whether or not an electron in an atom is actually in motion, but it will keep doing what it does until the universe winks out, if it's shielded from all radiation.

Comment: @S. McGrew, I do agree with you but perfect sheilding is impossible for any system. And that's not a technical challenge, its rooted in physics.

Comment: In general, "perfect" is difficult to achieve.  But if the likelihood of interaction is so low that the motion will probably continue unabated for the expected life of the universe, I'm willing to pretend the motion is perpetual.

Comment: Ah..I get your point. By that definition then its definitely possible after ignoring a tonne of physics